# How can I install all brew packages listed in a text file?

Tags: homebrew

Does Homebrew offer anything similar to pip's `pip install -r requirements.txt` feature? I have a new MacBook Pro arriving today, so one of the first tasks will be to migrate my brew installations. I've already performed a `brew list > brew.txt` command. Will I be able to use this to install all the packages it lists in one command on the new machine?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do `brew leaves > my_brews.txt` and then on the new machine do
 `for i in $(cat brew_leaves); do; brew install "$i"; done`. You can use newlines where there are semicolons above. [assuming bash]

Comment: Would `brew install $(cat my_brews.txt)` not accomplish the same in one single invocation of `brew`, without the need of a `for` loop?

Comment: I think the newlines in my_brews.txt would mess you up. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, works either way for me. Bash scans the results of the `$(cat` … `)`parameter expansion and then [uses either of the space, newline, and tab characters to split words](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) as if they were all the same (unless you have set some weird value for `IFS`, in which case either approach would fail).

Comment: `while read formula; do brew install "$formula"; done < my_brews.txt` avoids the useless use of cat.

Answer (score 43):

```
brew leaves > my_brew.txt
xargs brew install < my_brew.txt
```

Use xargs instead of a for loop to avoid IFS.

Comment: Currently the best answer bc it doesn't require any additional libs being installed to use.

Answer (score 15):

MERM provided a working answer, but others may be interested in a solution that, while not included with Homebrew, is published by the same people. [Homebrew bundle](https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-bundle) is a brew package that is designed for this purpose, also handling casks and, I think, Mac App Store apps (with the [mas](https://github.com/mas-cli/mas) package).

Comment: Just an addition to this, you can use `brew bundle dump` to create a file of everything that you have installed currently, transfer the output file to another computer, and run `brew bundle` to install everything.

Comment: This comment should be the answer: `brew bundle dump` and `brew bundle` are just what I needed!

Comment: I concur that brew bundle is now the way to go.  I switched to this method myself.